# Image not rendering in meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor

I'm using `collectionFs` to upload and display images.

Everything works perfectly except that when I try to display the image in the template nothing happens.

If I write `{{this.url}}` the url displays perfectly

```
/cfs/files/images/GkPAjn98N6izJYc6x/blogging.jpg
```

However if I write `<img src="{{this.url}}">` nothing happens
Any idea why this is?

Comment: I had the same problem, doing everything apparently correctly but browser would not display image in img tag. Worked just fine if I opened the url in a separate tab. No explanation for why, but restarting the browser fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the element what you get?

you get `<im src="/cfs/files/images/GkPAjn98N6izJYc6x/blogging.jpg"/>`

Also be sure you have the allow download to true

```
Images.allow({
 download:function(){return true;}
})
```

Check out this [DEMO](http://demo.fscollection.meteor.com)

**NOTE**: do a meteor list and check that you have the latest version of `cfs:stander:packages` and `cfs:gridfs` or filesystem

Comment: I get `<img src="/cfs/files/images/GkPAjn98N6izJYc6x/blogging.jpg?token=eyJhdXRoVG9rZW4iOiI1ZFZJVEQ3Vy03T2pQbndkTTEyTHpFY0o5QmI4eTlpTHVITFRhcUtqbkgzIn0%3D" alt="" class="thumbnail" width="300" height="100">` I already have the download permission set correctly and everything is up to date. Not sure what is not making it work :S

Comment: I'm not sure why, but it started working when I closed everything and open everything back again. thanks!